# Windows - CreateProcess detach child

Tags: windows, process, subprocess, kill, createprocess

I want to create a child process that is detached from the parent, so that if the parent exits, the child process will continue. I'm working on Windows and did this:

```
if(CreateProcess(program, arguments, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_NO_WINDOW | DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo))
{
   CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);
   CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
}
```

In my case the parent continues running while the child executes in the background. If I press Ctrl-C in the terminal to kill the parent, the child continues executing - as intended. However, if I kill the parent in Window's task manager, the child is also killed.

Why is there a difference between Ctrl-C and the killing in the task manager? Any way to ensure the child continues, even if the parent is killed in the task manager?

Comment: you must not do(wait for child) what you try do now. you at all nothing need do. child process is not depended from parent and will be run if parent exit

Comment: Sorry for that confusion. detach in my case is true, so I actually don't wait. I removed it from the code now.

Comment: in windows child process absolute not depended from parent (if not special design for this)

Comment: Normally a console application either inherits its parent's console or allocates a new one if the parent doesn't have a console. You can force allocating a new console with either `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`. The latter is a new console (conhost.exe) that doesn't have a window (it's not merely hidden). You can also force it to run without a console (i.e. detached) via the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag. Combining `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` with either `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or `DETACHED_PROCESS` is harmless nonsense that Windows ignores.

Comment: The console reports one of its attached processes (typically the one that allocated the console) as the effective owner of the window (it's not really the owner, i.e. the window procedure executes in conhost.exe). Task Manager or taskkill.exe will attempt to gracefully kill the process that's effectively the owner of the console by sending a `WM_CLOSE` message to the console window. The side effect is that the console will then kill every process attached to it, each of which has 5 seconds to handle the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` before getting terminated by Windows (csrss.exe).

Comment: If the console reports the parent as the effective owner of the window, then killing the parent will try the graceful `WM_CLOSE` approach. You're creating the child detached from the console, but if it's calling `AttachConsole` to attach back to the parent's console, then what you describe is possible, i.e. killing the parent will kill the child. Otherwise I don't see a way for this to happen, unless you're not showing us code where you set the child in a Job object that kills the child when the parent exits.

Comment: Any updates on this?